# Docker vs Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant, виртуализация

Есть необходимость в команде использовать локально среду, идентичную или приближенную к реальному продукту. Есть опыт использования Vagrant(VirtualBox + Vagrant + Homestead), но еще посоветовали Docker, с ним знакомство только по статьям.

Есть ли смысл использовать его вместо Vagrant?

Стек технологий такой: Node.js, php, redis, MySql, возможно в ближайшее время добавится обработка очередей задач.

За мануалы или статьи буду благодарен.

Comment: Vagrant это же вроде только управление виртуалками, вы с чем собираетесь его использовать, VirtualBox, LXC или еще чем?

Comment: @ilyapt VirtualBox + Vagrant + Homestead

Comment: тогда это очень-очень разные решения. Ваш вариант это виртуализация, с полноценной ос и кучей сервисов, а Docker это по сути сильно продвинутый chroot с одним сервисом внутри.

И у них совершенно разные задачи:
- виртуализацией вы можете воссоздать среду, приближенную к реальному серверу.
- докером можете сделать переносимые контейнеры с сервисами.

Comment: Например у вас есть докер файл, описывающий контейнер с php-fpm и вашим кодом. Вы вносите изменения в код, запускаете локально сборку контейнера, проверяете, что все работает, отправляете контейнер в локальный репозиторий. На сервере ставите контейнер из репозитория, отключаете контейнер с предыдущей версий, подключаете новый. При этом остальные контейнеры (с nginx, redis, etc) вообще не трогаете.

Comment: если есть такая необходимость стоит присмотреться к коду проэкта, и квалификации команды

Comment: @Naumov а что плохого в таком подходе каждый человек использует одинаковую среду, в итоге нет потребности следить что то версия не та какой-то библиотеки то нет чего-то.

Comment: @ilyapt разница в уровне виртуализации, на уровне ядра или полноценная, не более

Comment: @Etki VmWare vSphere и FreeBSD jails тоже разницы не много, только в уровне виртуализации. А предназначение решений, их возможности и инфраструктура — это мелочи, на которые можно не обращать внимание.

Comment: @ilyapt у виртуализации в данном контексте разные возможности?

Comment: @Etki если сравнивать именно виртуализацию, то есть VirtualBox для Vagrant и LXC для Docker-а, то разница действительно только в уровне виртуализации. Если же сравнивать инфраструктуры, то возможности, а главное задачи у Docker, Vagrant и vSphere разные.

Comment: @ilyapt ну и есть для ТС здесь криминальная разница?

Comment: @Etki ваш вопрос про разницу в виртуализации или в инфраструктуре?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## Что такое Vagrant и Docker?

В общем и целом, под Docker и Vagrant имеют в виду просто средства виртуализации с разной степенью этой виртуализации, Docker - как средство виртуализации на уровне ядра Linux (теперь не только Linux, но не берусь говорить, как обстоит дело на маке и окнах), Vagrant - как полную виртуализацию (затрудняюсь даже корректно охарактеризовать, что это такое, но если в первом случае все происходит внутри ядра Linux, то тут машина виртуализуется полностью, и ей предоставляются виртуальные оперативные память, процессор, и прочие устройства - ВМ думает, что общается с железом, которого на самом деле не существует).
На самом деле все несколько иначе: Docker и вправду предоставляет вышеописанную виртуализацию, а Vagrant является просто менеджером средств виртуализации, и вышеприведенный пассаж про "полную виртуализацию" на самом деле относится к VirtualBox, которым управляет Vagrant. У Vagrant есть понятие провайдера (поставщика средстсв виртуализации), и Vagrant умеет управлять как VirtualBox, так и Docker.

## Зачем это нужно / что это позволяет сделать

Вы не указываете в своем вопросе, какие именно цели преследуете, поэтому придется написать, какие вообще проблемы это решает и какие проблемы *принято* решать тем или иным инструментом.

У виртуализации как таковой есть много приятных бонусов, в том числе:

- Простое и легкое ограничение процессов в ресурсах
- Изоляция ресурсов
- Возможность поставки не приложения как такового, а целиком готовое решение, которое нужно не *установить и настроить*, а просто *запустить*
- Косвенным образом - повторяемость процессов

Это очень хорошо с точки зрения инфраструктуры, потому что это позволяет перейти от модели *сломалось -> починил* к модели *сломалось -> развернул заново*, что гораздо проще автоматизируется и экономит тучу ресурсов.

С точки зрения разработки появляются два ключевых плюса, которые могут поменять парадигму разработки:

- Сборка приложения внутри виртуальной машины переворачивает ситуацию из "работает на моей машине" в "работает в этой виртуальной машине". Инженер, который должен развернуть приложение, получая его в образе виртуальной машины, знает, что для запуска нужно обеспечить только запуск самого образа, тратит процентов на девяносто меньше времени на разруливание ошибок запуска.
- Использование виртуальных машин позволяет разработчику полностью сымитировать инфраструктуру, в которой проект будет развернут, что опять же позволяет снизить издержки с известной проблемой "на моей машине все работает" и держать несколько версий ПО для разных проектов (если проект А использует PHP 5.3, а проект Б использует PHP 7.0, то вместо жонглирования версиями на рабочей машине разработчик может их держать в отдельных изолированных машинах).

В данном случае, конечно, интересует второй момент.

И Vagrant + VirtualBox, и Docker позволяют его реализовать, поэтому принципиальной разницы нет, поэтому имеет смысл просто описать концепции обоих инструментов.

VirtualBox сам по себе является просто менеджером виртуальных машин, который позволяет запускать их из образов. Здесь все просто: берется образ файлов системы, эмулируется процессор, оперативная память, жесткий диск, виртуальная машина ищет бут-сеткор на виртуальном диске, и машина дальше стартует, как будто она реальна.

Vagrant является менеджером средств виртуализации, и на самом деле может запускать не только VirtualBox, но и Docker. Конкретно в данном разрезе Vagrant позволяет автоматизировать создание виртуальной машины (или виртуальных машин) VirtualBox из образа чистой операционной системы, применив т.н. провизию - инициализировав машину с помощью shell-скрипта или менеджера конфигурации.

Docker сам по себе предоставляет ровно такой же функционал виртуализации, но очень сильно отличается в плане концепции. Он использует следующий функционал для реализации своих целей:

- Copy-On-Write систему слоев для реализации файловой системы. Конечная файловая система собирается из нескольких слоев, в результате чего изображения могут делить нижние слои, а для каждой виртуальной машины используется свой собственный слой (верхний в этой композиции), поэтому машины могут использовать общую базу, которую не нужно копировать для старта машины.
- Систему пространств имен в ядре Linux (опять же затрудняюсь сказать, как это организовано в Mac/Windows)

Это позволяет относиться к машинам, как к расходному материалу и пересоздавать их сотни раз в секунду (это очень быстрый процесс по сравнению с поднятием полноценной виртуальной машины). Благодаря этому сформировалась философия Docker, в которой принято правило process-per-container (один процесс на контейенер), и вместо распространения виртуальных машин концепция Docker подразумевает распространение приложений, каждое из которых завернуто в свой образ виртуальной машины для изоляции.

С точки зрения виртуализации внутри происходит практически то же самое что и с обычной виртуальной машиной: запускается корневой процесс, который поднимает все остальные. В образах Vagrant-VirtualBox обычно используется привычный init, в Docker-образах - само приложение, таким образом получается, что в виртуальной машине Vagrant-Virtualbox запускается менеджер ОС, следящий за всем происходящем, а в Docker-образе - ничего, кроме конечного приложения.

Поэтому при использовании инфраструктуры Docker ключевым отличием станет то, что Vagrant+Virtualbox обычно используется для поднятия одной машины со всем на свете, а в случае с Docker будет поднято по контейнеру на каждый сервис (redis, база данных, сервис очередей, etc.).

Таким образом Virtualbox + Vagrant и Docker различаются главным образом концепцией, которая не несет функциональной разницы. Тем не менее, нельзя не отметить, что коммьюнити для каждого инструмента больше развито в том направлении, в котором используется сам инструмент: используя Docker, вы сможете пользоваться общедоступными изолированными машинами с одним процессом в каждой машине и конфигурацией через переменные окружения, используя Vagrant, вы получаете доступ к машинам, конфигурируемым через configuration manager (chef, puppet, saltstack) или и вовсе просто через shell-скрипт и готовым к установке большого количества сервисов на одну машину.

## Есть ли разница

В комментариях к вопросу я занял позицию "криминальной разницы между ними нет", и намерен продолжать ее занимать.

Что Vagrant-поверх-VirtualBox, что Docker на самом деле предоставляют один и тот же функционал:

- Виртуальная машина с одним корневым процессом (строго говоря, так вообще все машины работают)
- Распространяемые образы этих виртуальных машин
- Возможность проброса портов виртуальной машины на хост
- Возможность монтирования директорий хоста внутрь виртуальной машины
- Возможность организации внутренней сети виртуальных машин
- Возможность запуска/остановки композиции виртуальных машин
- Возможность сохранения, выгрузки и загрузки снэпшота виртуальной машины
- Ограничение виртуальной машины по ресурсам

Поэтому на самом деле никакой функциональной разницы, на чем вы будете строить свою инфраструктуру, нет: вы можете ровно так же перевести vagrant на философию "один процесс на машину" или запихнуть все на свете в один docker-container. Однако, у Docker есть ряд преимуществ, не влияющих на сам функционал виртуализации, которые просто делают его использование более удобным и экономным (и которые сформировали его философию):

- Отсутствие расходов на полноценную виртуализацию
- COW-система слоев, которая позволяет экономить место при использовании нескольких машин с общим предком
- Практически мгновенный запуск за счет того, что не нужно инициализировать систему (загружать ядро, монтировать диски и весь тот невероятный парк операций, который происходит при включении машины), и контейнеру остается только запустить бинарник, указанный для него точкой входа.

Из-за этого цикл жизни контейнера (на машине разработчика), как правило, гораздо короче, чем у виртуальной машины (и, бонусом, это позволяет обнулить базу данных практически одной командой).

Обращение с Docker может быть немного более сложным, но накладные расходы на запуск-остановку композиции сервисов снижаются, а экспорт конечного приложения в виде образа виртуальной машины может быть менее трудоемким, чем в случае с Vagrant + VirtualBox. Тем не менее, сам vagrant я не стал бы списывать со счетов, потому что, пока мир не перешел на контейнерные технологии целиком, он ближе воссоздает целевое окружение (одну машину со всем установленным внутри), да и, к тому же, никто не запрещает использовать его в связке с Docker.

Comment: Хотел бы также поныть про какую-то фантастическую безграмотность в соседних ответах. Они, может, будут и точнее отвечать автору, чем эта портянка, но фактические ошибки просто какие-то дикие.

Answer (score 10):

Docker и Vagrant немного разные вещи.

Docker - по сути это некий контейнер в который вы можете засунуть операционную систему, свой софт и базу данных и запустить его. У контенеров есть слои, ОС - нижний слой, софт выше слой, и ваше приложение и данные - верхний слой. Контенеры удобны для переноса приложения и сопровождающего окружения на сервер или в облако. Docker не создает виртуальную систему, а только эмулирует ее пробрасывая системные вызовы и работает стабильно только в Linux. С недавнего времени появилась версия для MacOS. Обычно сброка бокса описана в файле Dockerfile.

Vagrant, же, напротив - базируется на системах виртуализации (VirtualBox, libvirt, xen). С самого начала он создает полноценную виртуальную машину, выполняет скрипт provision, который устанавливает все окружение и настраивает его. Vagrant работает на всех операционных системах в силу своей природы.

Обычно для локальной разработки используется Vagrant. Он в принципе для этого и предназначен. Вы запустили виртуальную машину, поигрались с ней и снесли ее. Или пересобрали заново. Есть поле для экспериментов.

Docker же работает как сборщик софта в некий ящик, который удобно двигать потом куда-то и где-то запускать.

В любом случае полезно попробовать обе системы.

Comment: Docker для Windows также работает стабильно и появился еще в начале августа - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Comment: Хорошее замечание, спасибо.

Answer (score 9):

> **Vargant** - готовая виртуальная машина
>
> **Docker** - набор изолированных контейнеров

Докер можно назвать изоляцией от окружения (настроек) операционной системы. Смысл Docker - чтобы можно было запусить программу почти где угодно, не настраивая ее под другую ОС (не устанавливая библиотек, не прописывая путей, портов, не создавая настроечных файлов по возможности и пр.).

Мы используем в команде Docker со связкой docker-compose, разворачивание всего проекта сводится к команде `docker-compose up -d` и описанием каких-то специфических environment переменных в файле для текущей машины (переменные окружения - это удобно).

Изменения не затрагивают твою операционную систему и можно работать над несколькими проектами одновременно, оно не сильно тратит ресурсы компьютера, нет необходимости беспокоиться что не будет какой-то библиотеки.

Удобно тестировать, как твой проект работает на новой версии какого-то ПО, описал новый контейнер с PHP 7.1 в файле, вместо PHP 7, перекинул порты и проверил как у тебя проект лег на новую версию. Подцепил новую системную библиотеку, пересобрал за несколько минут, не запустилось, раскоментировал строчку со старой библиотекой, пересобрал и все опять впорядке.

Есть минусы в виде настройки сети, логирования, управления, но с каждым релизом разработчики пытаются исправить все существующие проблемы.

Comment: Если не сложно могли бы вы дать ссылку на мануал по сбору проекта, какого-то элементарного с конектом в бд  и php. Либо если не лень рассказать самому )

Comment: @Shadow33 Вот здесь очень хорошо все описано: https://ast.rocks/blog/docker-create-container - слишком много тонкостей, я вам их описать не могу, т.к. это надо книжку написать :)

Answer (score 5):

Работал с Vagrant и Docker.

Vagrant очень удобен для того чтоб создать виртуальную машину в которой данные будут жить между `vagrant up` и `vagrant halt` - долго, что очень нужно когда ты работаешь над проектом. Использовать контейнеры для в данном случае не совсем уместно.

Vagrant позволяет установить box с операционной системой которая будет на production. Дальше устанавливаются инструменты которые будут крутиться вместе. Пишется ansible / puppet / chief / salt / bash provision скрипт, корорый все поднимает на `vagrant up`. Созданный бокс можно спокойно упаковать и отправить хранилище. После этого новый разработчик скачивает бокс и поднимает его и получает готовый энв для разработки. Цикл жизни данных длительный и между остановкой все сохраняется в отличие от Docker (Volumes не берем, они там не нужны).

Docker очень удобен если надо протестировать полученный результат на определенном наборе данных. Запустил, проверил, удалил.

Конечно докер можно использовать delivery to production, это очень удобно НО, если проект не сложный и состоит максимум 1 - 2, не считаем db, servers. Docker-compose еще очень сырой чтоб запускать его в production из-за того, что он не может управлять связями между приложениями достаточно хорошо.

Если нужен инструмент для приближения к боевому серверу и таблетку от головной боли для новых разработчиков смело используйте Vagrant.

Comment: *между остановкой все сохраняется в отличие от Docker* - да что вы говорите

Answer (score 5):

Для создания идентичного окружения подходит как *Docker* (создание контейнеров), так и *vagrant* (создание бокса, который можно расшарить).
При этом стоит помнить, что *Docker* немного из другой оперы. Каждое приложение нужно будет упаковывать в отдельный контейнер, что заставит Вас выполнять лишние телодвижения.

Советую связку из *Vagrant* + *Ansible*. Разница будет в команде инициализации (`docker-compose up -d` против `vagrant up`), но изменять окружение будет гораздо комфортней, гибче и быстрей, а также Вы будете лишены ненужных прослоек и ограничений которые есть в *Docker*.

**Обновление #1**

Ненужные прослойки для Вас, а не для Docker.
Я говорил про всё что связано с *Net*,*FS*, и т.д.
Возьмём для примера *Celery* - распределённую очередь заданий.
Установка довольна проста: поставили *Python*, установили *Celery*, открыли конфиг и настроили как Вам надо, дополнительно поставили веб морду.

Всё очень просто, но не в случае использования *Docker*:

1. Создать контейнера для *Celery* сервера, *Celery* воркеров, веб морды.
2. Настроить порты для связи.
3. Расшарить конфиг на все контейнеры.

Дополнительно, допустим Ваши воркеры должены запускать задачи написанные на PHP. Это значит что контейнеры должны содержать дополнительно PHP.

Возможно звучит как дело 5мин, но на деле на такие задачи может уйти спокойно половина дня.

PS: Сам использовал изначально связку *Vagrant* + *puppet*. Но отказался от неё, т.к. с *puppet* были постоянные проблемы(в процессе установки, иногда мог пропасть интернет на секунду, или по другим причинам приложение могло вернуть код ошибки. Из-за этого валился весь процесс установки).

Это сподвигло меня перейти на Docker(отдельные составные части). На самом деле когда всё уже настроено то и нормально, но вот вещи которые меня в нём очень бесят(для данного рода задач)

1. БД в контейнере - выбора нет, а вот проблем много. Подводные камни могут проявляться в течении всего цикла разработки.
2. Возможности Docker не упрощают, а только усугубляют процесс разработки.

**Обновление #2**

Docker отличная вещь, но он для другого. Вы можете использовать его, но готовьтесь к шаманствам. Например для монги или редиса нужно отключить THP, а в *docker* контейнере */sys/* в режиме *read-only*, из-за этого Вам всё-равно нужно будет править хост на котором крутиться *Docker*. Собирать кучу контейнеров тоже не всегда удобно. У Вас задача простая - создать единое окружение для группы программистов, т.е. в самом простом случае Вы можете просто расшарить образ виртуалки. Но это не совсем практично, более сложный вариант - создать скрипт который установит нужные зависимости, для этого достаточно *Vagrant* + сам скрипт. Более изящный вариант использовать менеджер конфигураций(*puppet* и подобные). У меня с puppet не сложилось, я выбрал *Ansible*(который сразу подойдёт для деплоя самого приложения).

Также не стоит оставлять в стороне вопросы процессов внутри команды - очень часто после того как разработчик забрал изменения из репозитория, ему нужно выполнить набор действий(миграции, чистка кеша, т.п.). Данную цепочку действий можно возложить на плечи *Ansible*.

Comment: Какие ненужные прослойки необходимы докеру ?

Comment: Ненужные прослойки для Вас, а не для Docker.
Я говорил про всё что связано с Net, FS, и т.д.

Comment: как будто при обычном развертывании нет ни файловой системы, ни сети

Comment: Они общая. В этом та вся и разница.

Comment: @qRoC Спасибо  за ответ, просто в данный момент стоит выбор перед пересобрать полностью репозиторий с вагрантом с целью развертывания проекта одной командой без шаманств `vagrant up` или взять сейчас и попробовать докер вроде как довольно много людей хвалят его.

Comment: @Shadow33 дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 4):

**Docker** имхо имеет смысл использовать только тогда когда необходима динамически расширяемая инфраструктура. Т.е. в облаке. А также если в компании множество различных окружений на prod серверах и при этом на них используется Docker.
В противном случае это просто лишняя трата времени.

Вот пример.
Нам надо поменять что то в инфраструктуре одного сервера.
В случае если бы мы не использовали Docker нам надо было бы просто изменить пару строк в Ansible (или подобной) и запустить плейбук с тегом нужного софта. 3-5-10 сек и все готово.

В случае с Docker необходимо пересобрать весь образ (5-10-20 минут) 
Если правок много то, можно забыть над чем вообще работал.
Далее...

**Docker и MacOS:**

1. При монтировании папки в хост систему внутри докера папки принимают права 1000:staff. Да, решается, но в среднем у людей уходит дня 2-3 (из тех что знаю) чтобы найти ответ.
2. Скорость синхронизации нативного драйвера. Многие решают через использование NFS, либо rsync/unison-based специального(!) софта
3. Все что использует [mmap](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) на смонтированных в хост систему разделах будет вылетать с критикалами. Например MongoDB.

Помимо прочего все образы надо где то хранить чтобы передавать.
И если вы не хотите выкладывать в открытый доступ, то придется поискать сервис, либо организовать свой сервер, который надо будет поддерживать.

Если вопрос только о локальном окружении - Docker точно не ваш вариант.

**Vagrant** в этом плане лучше, но и там есть подводные камни.
Например в nginx sendfile не работает.
Билдить боксы тоже надо целиком.

**Что делать?**
Для себя я взял VPS, ансиблом за несколько секунд донакатываю необходимые обновления. 
Раз в месяц делаю полный апдейт.
Настроил one-way репликацию [dklab_realsync](http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realsync/) (в статье обосновано почему one-way достаточно).
Все пакетные менеджеры, Git итп отрабатывают локально, и потом происходит репликация.

**Преимущества:**

1. Первичная репликация занимает не больше минуты.
2. Легко показать работу коллегам / заказчикам. Сервер всегда доступен из вне.
3. Все настраивается в разы проще и порог вхождения    минимален.

Answer (score 1):

`Docker:` Мануалов в сети полно. С точки зрения оркестровки, контейнеры очень удобны, когда у Вас есть кластер серверов, решений масса.

Мы уже 1.5 года используем [rancher.com](http://rancher.com) (opensource).

Docker легче и быстрее в изучении, а также в эксплуатации ИМХО