# Различие между терминами "слой" и "контейнер" в Docker

Tags: администрирование, веб-сервер, docker, сборка

Решил пощупать Docker-технологию для запуска приложений, и в процессе чтения появился вопрос.

**В одних источниках используется термин "слой", в других "контейнер"**. 
Это одно и то же - "образ + новое приложение"?

Например, к образу пустой системы добавил nginx - **СЛОЙ 1** готов. К образу пустой системы добавил uWSGI - **СЛОЙ 2** готов.

**Контейнеры уже входят в образы?** Или контейнер это образ, запущенный на хосте с нужными параметрами?

Comment: Вот отличный ответ, если ещё не читали — рекомендую. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573492/181472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Образ** - это метаинформация + **aufs раздел** с файлами. **Контейнер** - это **образ** который запущен/остановлен. **aufs раздел** с файлами состоит из слоев. 
**Слой** - это слепок раздела, который содержит измененные и новые файлы. Все **слои** внутри **aufs раздела** только для чтения, для записи можно использовать только самый новый (верхний) слой. Когда происходит запуск контейнера, то создается новый **слой** и все изменения попадают в него.

Предположим, что есть вот такой **aufs раздел**:

```
Слои   Содержимое
      +-----------+
3     | file1.txt |
      +-----------+
2     | file3.txt |
      +-----------+
1     | file1.txt |
      | file2.txt |
      +-----------+
```

Процесс внутри этого раздела будет видеть файлы

```
 file1.txt из 3 слоя
 file2.txt из 1 слоя
 file3.txt из 2 слоя
```

Если процесс попробует записать что-то в файлы file2.txt, filе4.txt и удалить file1.txt, то получиться вот так

```
Слои   Содержимое
      +-------------+
3     | file2.txt   |
      | file4.txt   |
      | <directory> | - директория это файл в котором будет
      +-------------+   удалена информация о файле file1.txt
3     | file1.txt   |   т.е. file1.txt пропадет.
      +-------------+
2     | file3.txt   |
      +-------------+
1     | file1.txt   |
      | file2.txt   |
      +-------------+
```

В юникс-системах директории - это файлы в которых содержится информация о других файлах. При удалении файла с диска происходит изменение файла директории.

Comment: добавил про слой

Comment: о, спасибо. структура образа напоминает гит-репозиторий

Comment: да. идея похожая. и у docker есть команда `diff` которая показывает разницу между образами.

Comment: Не поделитесь ссылкой да документацию по слоям  (layers)